# Backbone.Collection.model is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model and it's collection, for example:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel
});
```

but when I try `console.log(JSON.stringify(MyCollection.model));`, it returns `undefined` rather than `MyModel`.

Is there any my misunderstanding with `Backbone.Collection` or errors in my code?

Comment: The `model` property is on `MyCollection`'s prototype so either look at `MyCollection.prototype.model` or `new MyCollection().model`.

Comment: @muistooshort it's now returning `child()` method, which I totally don't get what it does..

Comment: Check `MyCollection.prototype.model === MyModel` and keep in mind that JavaScript doesn't have classes. What is behind this question? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @muistooshort Ah it worked, thank you for kind comment on my ambiguous question. It seems like the problem is that I'm not fully understanding javascript's prototype oriented paradigm.